# "spring.data.web.pageable.one-indexed-parameters=true" does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

in my Spring Boot Rest Service I want to implement a getAll method with pagination for lazy loading in frontend later.

At the moment I have to request with page 0 if I want the first set of rows. With the following config inserted in the application.properties it should work...
     spring.data.web.pageable.one-indexed-parameters=true
... but it doesn't.

Does anybody knows why or is this a legacy way? I'm using spring-boot-starter-web and data-jpa in version 2.0.4.RELEASE.

Thanks a lot!

edit, here is the service method, maybe PageRequest can't handle this.

```
public List<TransactionResponseDTO> findAll(int pageNumber, int     pageSize) {

    List<TransactionResponseDTO> transactionResponseDTOs = new ArrayList<>();

    PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize);

    List<TransactionEntity> transactionEntities =
    transactionRepository.findAll(pageRequest).getContent();

    for (TransactionEntity transactionEntity : transactionEntities) {
        transactionResponseDTOs.add(convert(transactionEntity));
    }

    return transactionResponseDTOs;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The property **spring.data.web.pageable.one-indexed-parameters=true** only controls the behaviour of how to automatically bind pagination parameters to a web request handler method's **Pageable** argument.

**Case 1:** The default behaviour which is **spring.data.web.pageable.one-indexed-parameters=false** and when a request is made with *http://localhost:8080/api/customers?**page=5***

```
@GetMapping("/api/customers")
public List<Customer> getCustomers(Pageable pageable) {
   //here pageable.getPageNumber() == 5
   Page<Customer> customersPage = customerRepository.findAll(pageable);
   //here customersPage.getNumber() == 5
}
```

**Case 2:** With **spring.data.web.pageable.one-indexed-parameters=true** and when a request is made with http://localhost:8080/api/customers?page=5

```
@GetMapping("/api/customers")
public List<Customer> getCustomers(Pageable pageable) {
   //here pageable.getPageNumber() == 4
   Page<Customer> customersPage = customerRepository.findAll(pageable);
   //here customersPage.getNumber() == 4
}
```

Note that once you get the data **Page customersPage** if you check **customersPage.getNumber()** it will simply return what is there in **pageable.getPageNumber()** which is 4. We might expect 5 hoping one-indexed-parameters would return 5 using 1-based indexing but that's not the case.

Comment: How can I get pageNumber attribute also to give me one based index result ?

Answer (score 4):

```
@Configuration
public class PageableConfig {

    @Bean
    PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer pageableResolverCustomizer() {
        return pageableResolver -> pageableResolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer so others know how your code works.

Comment: in sdr ,the SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration will config after RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration and on missing bean PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver,but  RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration has bean PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver by pageableResolver(),so the SpringDataWebProperties will not be work. forunately, the method pageableResolver calls the method customizePageableResolver ,and it can be configed by PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer to customizer the PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.

Comment: this working for me, i am writing inside existing configuration class.

Answer (score 1):

i think that is bug . see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14413

`SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration` should before `RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration`，this makes `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer` not work ,so cofig yml `spring.data.web.pageable` not work

Answer (score 0):

You need  to add paging support to your Repositories, you need to extend the

```
PagingAndSortingRepository<T,ID>
```

interface rather than the basic

```
CrudRepository<T,ID>
```

interface. This adds methods that accept a Pageable to control the number and page of results returned.

```
public Page findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

Check it here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/paging-chapter.html

Comment: since O.P is clearly using the PageRequest, it's pretty safe to assume that they are already using a PagingAndSortingRepository, no?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Unfortunately your solution does also not work. The first page of pagination is still 0 and not 1. Anyway thanks for the support! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of confustions about this on the internet. Here is the link to read more about it https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14413.

Since this is not a solution to the original question but it may help dealing with this issue.

Create a utility class to create the `PageRequest` and then parse the **paging information** from the Page you get from the repository.

**Explaination**
It just reduces the page number from the request and increases in the response. That's how the API consumer will always have one indexed page.

`PagintUtils` class.

```
public class PagingUtils {
    public static PagingInfoDto getPagingInfoFromPage(Page page){
        PagingInfoDto pagingInfoDto = new PagingInfoDto();
        int currentPage = page.getNumber() + 1;
        pagingInfoDto.setCurrentPage(currentPage);
        pagingInfoDto.setTotalPages(page.getTotalPages());
        pagingInfoDto.setTotalItems(page.getTotalElements());
        pagingInfoDto.setItemPerPage(page.getSize());
        return pagingInfoDto;
    }

    public static PageRequest getPageRequest(int pageNumber, int pageSize){
        return PageRequest.of(--pageNumber, pageSize);
    }
}
```

To use it for example in service layer.

```
Pageable pageable = PagingUtils.getPageRequest(pageNumber, pageSize);
Page<CommentEntity> page = commentsRepository.getCommentReplies(commentId, pageable);
PagingInfoDto pagingInfoDto = PagingUtils.getPagingInfoFromPage(page);
```

It will retrun in the json as follows.

```
"PagingInfo": {
        "TotalPages": 3,
        "CurrentPage": 3,
        "TotalItems": 5,
        "ItemPerPage": 2
    }
```

`PagingInfoDto` class

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PagingInfoDto {
    private int totalPages;
    private int currentPage;
    private long totalItems;
    private int itemPerPage;
}
```