# What is the easiest way to start pagination results at 1 with Spring Data JPA?

Tags: pagination, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In some other places I saw people suggesting to set:

`spring.data.web.pageable.one-indexed-parameters=true`

However, this is not changing anything in the behavior of my application. I've put this on the properties file of my SpringBoot application.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: If you are using Spring Data Rest then possible bug. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52120070/spring-data-web-pageable-one-indexed-parameters-true-does-not-work and here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14413

Answer (score 1):

**My problem** 
I wanted this endpoint: `profiles?page=1&size=10` to start pagination results at `page=1` not `page=0`.

**My solution** 
I have set `defaultValue` for page as `1`:
`@RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "1")`

Changed method argument for `returnPaginatedProfiles` to `page - 1`. So now for page=1 repository under the hood will return me page=0: `returnPaginatedProfiles(page - 1, size)`  
Code for Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/profiles")
public String getPaginatedProfiles(@RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "1") int page,
                                   @RequestParam(value = "size", defaultValue = "10") int size) {
    Page<Profile> profilePage = profileService.returnPaginatedProfiles(page - 1, size);
    // Unimportant code logic...
}
```

Code for Service:

```
public Page<Profile> returnPaginatedProfiles(int page, int size) {
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size);
    return profileRepository.findAll(pageable);
}
```

Comment: This works! However, in the response object if you use `page.getNumber()` to get the current page you still get 0 for the first page and so on. To fix this I simply did `page.getNumber() + 1`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the PageableDefault annotation, i.e. `@PageableDefault(page = 1)` on your `Controller` method, e.g.:

```java
@RestController
public class Controller {

  public Page< DataEntity > getEntities(@PageableDefault(page = 1)Pageable pageable){
    //repository call here...
  }
}
```

Comment: Where would I put that? Can you provide a more elaborate example?

I have a `DataRepository` which `extends` `PagingAndSortingRepository<DataEntity, String>` , which has the methods .... are you suggesting I put that on top of one of it's methods that deals with pagination?

Comment: Putting it in the repository does not work for some reason. See edit above for an example of what I meant

Comment: If you set `@PageableDefault(page = 1)` you are to get the results for the **second** page, not the first page. Because, by default spring-data page indexes start from `0`. I think @Don_Code needs to change that indexing method so that first page has the index **1** instead of **0**.

Comment: @Johna I see what you mean, I may have misread the question and lost all context with this. I'll post an answer that satisfies the question in a moment. Thanks for clearing that one for me :)